# How to send and receive memory addresses via a socket in C?

Tags: c, sockets, void-pointers, memory-address

I want to send/receive a memory address via a socket in C.
What I have is the following:

```
void *ptr = malloc(122); /* So the pointer points to some valid address */
unsigned char *socketData = NULL;

socketData = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(void*));
memset(socketData, 0, sizeof(void*));

/* ??? How to get the memory address - where ptr points to - to socketData ??? */
```

I know that the way to print pointer addresses using `printf` is to use `%p`, i.e.

```
printf("%p", ptr);
```

But this prints for example 0x0021ef1a.
What I want is just the following: 0021ef1a

And on the receiver side: how to transform the received bytes back to a `void*`?

Ah: and the code should work for 32bit as well for 64bit systems ;)
Furthermore the code should compile using -Wall -Werror.... huh

Thanks for helping!
Have a nice weekend,
jonas

Comment: Did I understand this correctly, you want to send memoryaddresses to other machines/processes? If the receiving process is running on the same machine, I don't think it can access the memory allocated by the sending process (unless they're using some form of shared memory). If it's a completely different computer, the memory addresses are useless... unless used to refer to some resource on the other end, but I still wouldn't use raw memory addresses for safety, thinking of buffer overflow-attacks and such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, you can convert the raw data back to a pointer simply by copying again:

```
void *ptr = malloc(42);
void *ptr2 = NULL;

unsigned char *data = malloc(sizeof(void *));

memcpy(data, &ptr, sizeof(void *));

...

memcpy(&ptr2, data, sizeof(void *));

printf("ptr  = %p\n", ptr);
printf("ptr2 = %p\n", ptr2);
```

Note that in most situations, sending a pointer over sockets makes little sense.  The pointer value will be useless to the receiver, unless it happens to be the very same process as the sender.  Each process will have a separate virtual address space.

Given your proposed application, I would suggest that on the receiver side, you should consider representing this with a pointer at all, as it will be of no use in that form.  Instead, why not store it in a suitably-large integer type?

Comment: It makes sense if he wants to implement a memory checker for a device that can't output to a screen but can communicate to a computer through a socket.

Comment: hi oli & eric,

first of all thanks for your fast replies. I know that the memory address is not useful and useable at the receiver side because of the separate process spaces.

Nevertheless, do you have an idea how to accomplish this task?
@eric: that is exactly what i want to implement.
thanks! jonas

Comment: No need for `malloc`; `unsigned char data[sizeof(void *)];` would do.

Comment: @larsmans: Indeed.  But the buffer was there to represent the stream going in or out of the socket.

Comment: @Oli: yepp, the data stream going out/in consists usually of more than just the memory address, e.g. for malloc, the size of the allocated memory block.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to format a pointer as `printf()` does, to send to another host for display, then `sprintf()` may be the correct approach:

```
char dest[100] = "";
snprintf(dest, sizeof dest, "%p", ptr);
```

This creates a fixed-length string, which can be handled on the remote host as such.  The advantage of this is that it does not require the receiving host to know the details of the sending host's pointer size and format.